# regular expression for href from html page in php ?

Tags: php, regex

i want get  all`/farsi_persian/*/subtitle-*.aspx`  from one html page 
i try some regular expression on PHP but not find
can help me ?>

```
<a href="/farsi_persian/arrow-third-season/subtitle-1003059.aspx" title="Subtitle - Arrow - Third Season - Farsi/Persian"><span class="r0" title="Rating 0 out of 10">Farsi/Persian</span> Arrow - Third Season subtitle<br><small> Arrow.S03E03.HDTV.480p.x264-LOL </small></a>
```

Comment: Beter to use a DOM parser for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
/farsi_persian/[^/]+/subtitle-[^.]+.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myPattern = "/farsi_persian/[^/]+/subtitle-[^.]+.aspx";
preg_match_all($myPattern,$myText,$match);
var_dump($match);
```

it show null;

its worked

```
$myPattern = "/farsi_persian\/(.*.)\/subtitle-\d*.aspx/";
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), this might work::

```
preg_match_all('/\/farsi_persian\/[\w-]+\/subtitle-[\d]+.aspx/', $str, $matches);
```

assuming there's always numbers after `subtitle-`